# Echo individual array value

Tags: php

how can i echo individual value of the next array i'm gna post can someone tell me, i managed to echo all values with a for each loop but i want individual values because i need to insert them into database.
Thxn in advance.

```
global $ax_attributes;

$ax_attributes = array(
    'fullname' => array(
        'scheme'   => 'http://axschema.org/namePerson',
        'text'     => 'Celé jméno',
        'required' => FALSE
    ),
    'firstname' => array(
        'scheme'   => 'http://axschema.org/namePerson/first',
        'text'     => 'Jméno',
        'required' => TRUE
    ),
    'lastname' => array(
        'scheme'   => 'http://axschema.org/namePerson/last',
        'text'     => 'Příjmení',
        'required' => TRUE
    ),
    'nick' => array(
        'scheme'   => 'http://axschema.org/namePerson/friendly',
        'text'     => 'Přezdívka',
        'required' => FALSE
    ),
    'company' => array(
        'scheme'   => 'http://axschema.org/company/name',
        'text'     => 'Jméno společnosti',
        'required' => FALSE
    ),
    'h_address' => array(
        'scheme'   => 'http://axschema.org/contact/postalAddress/home',
        'text'     => 'Domácí adresa – Ulice',
        'required' => TRUE
    ),
    'h_address2' => array(
        'scheme'   => 'http://axschema.org/contact/postalAddressAdditional/home',
        'text'     => 'Domácí adresa – Ulice2',
        'required' => FALSE
    ),
    'h_address3' => array(
        'scheme'   => 'http://specs.nic.cz/attr/addr/main/street3',
        'text'     => 'Domácí adresa – Ulice3',
        'required' => FALSE
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide the key...

`echo $ax_attributes['nick']['scheme'];`

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
echo $ax_attributes['fullname']['scheme'];
```

Comment: Wrong, you don't provide an index when keys are associative values (key => value)

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that, edited

Comment: yea that was my mistake too providing index. thnx it's working